# Is there any way of using the labels/textboxes from one tabcontrol on another?

Tags: vb.net

Ive made an appointment system, however i would like to give my end user the ability to create more appointments on one day. I have used a Tabcontrol to do so. My question is; am i able to use the labels/texboxes used in tabcontrol1 on tabcontrol2 or do i have to create new ones?

Comment: You are talking about `TabPages` not `TabControl`. That's because you put controls in `TabPages` not in the `TabControl`... correct me if I am wrong? Either way it is possible, show what you have tried to do so far (attempt) and what's is going wrong. To guess what you want to do is kind of hard when nothing is given to work off of.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same controls on multiple tabs, don't put them on the tabs.  Put them somewhere off the tabs (left, top, right, or bottom).

Comment: Can you explain why to **not** put them where you said not to? What's the reason as why not to, what's the effects; I am curious.

Comment: If the OP is programmatically creating new TabPages with the same controls, what names will they have so you can pull the values from them.  Common controls between tab pages would be easier to manage if they are off the TabControl.  If each TabPage has unique controls then it makes sense to have them on there. IMO...